# How to present popUp when user taps on right bar button item?

Tags: ios, popupwindow, uistoryboardsegue

I'm relatively new at iOS. I'm struggling, for a while now with this issue. I don't know how to set the logic for presenting popUp when user taps on right bar button item. Basically, it should look like this:[PopUp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k16Zm.png) I searched through Google, but I didn't have any luck. I would appreciate if someone would help me with some code.

//My VC

```
     override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(clickShare))
        rightBarButtonItem.tintColor = UIColor.black
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButtonItem
   //     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Share", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(clickShare))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "backArrow"), style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(goBack))
        UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)! ], for: .normal)

    }

    //MARK: - Actions
   @objc func goBack() {
        navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }


    @objc func clickShare() {

    //this is where the logic should go
    }
```

//This is my storyboard:
[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDQHJ.png)

Comment: You can use `UIPopoverPresentationController`.  You can have a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uT4iGwLk0io).

Comment: Thanks, but I already saw this video.

Comment: Then what exactly do you want?

Comment: It' s ok, my friend. I resolved my problem. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following action,

```
@IBAction func yourButtonClickAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourViewController") as! UIViewController
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Popover
    let popover: UIPopoverPresentationController = vc.popoverPresentationController!
    popover.barButtonItem = sender
    popover.delegate = self
    presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion:nil)
}
```

Add this action to you barButtonItem.
'YourViewController' = controller consisting of Public, followers options.